# Question about self made touches function of Swift

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit

How could I call the `func movePlayer`

```
func movePlayer( touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    guard currentGameState == gameState.inGame else { return }

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        if pointOfTouch.x > gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2 {
            pointOfTouch.x = gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2
        }
        if pointOfTouch.x < gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2 {
            pointOfTouch.x = gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2
        }
        if pointOfTouch.y > gameArea.maxY - player.size.height/2 {
            pointOfTouch.y = gameArea.maxY - player.size.height/2
        }
        if pointOfTouch.y < gameArea.minY + player.size.height/2 {
            pointOfTouch.y = gameArea.minY + player.size.height/2
        }
    }
}
```

Properly inside the

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard currentGameState == gameState.preGame else { return }
    startGame()
}
```

I already tried to call it normally like:

```
movePlayer()
```

but it didn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard currentGameState == gameState.preGame else { return }
    startGame()
    self.movePlayer(touches: touches, with: event)
}


func movePlayer( touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    guard currentGameState == gameState.inGame else { return }

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        if pointOfTouch.x > gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2 {
            pointOfTouch.x = gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2
        }
        if pointOfTouch.x < gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2 {
            pointOfTouch.x = gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2
        }
        if pointOfTouch.y > gameArea.maxY - player.size.height/2 {
            pointOfTouch.y = gameArea.maxY - player.size.height/2
        }
        if pointOfTouch.y < gameArea.minY + player.size.height/2 {
            pointOfTouch.y = gameArea.minY + player.size.height/2
        }
    }
}
```